# Treeview не растягивается на все окно

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Есть небольшая программа и там нужна таблица, но она не растягивается на все окно в чем может быть проблема?

[image: Почему оно держится слева и не растягивается]

```
class Main (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill = tk.X)

        btn_open_About = tk.Button(toolbar, text='О программе', command=self.open_About, bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0,
                                   compound=tk.TOP)
        btn_open_About.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.Frm1 = tk.Frame()
        self.Frm1.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.Frm1, columns=('ID', 'name', 'phone'), height=15, show='headings')

        self.tree.column('ID', width=50, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('name', width=50, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('phone', width=50, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading('ID', text='ID')
        self.tree.heading('name', text='Имя контакта')
        self.tree.heading('phone', text='Номер телефона')

        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set)

        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def open_About(self):
        About()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы ячейка с деревом расширялась, `rowconfigure` и `columnconfigure` нужно вызывать для фрейма, в котором дерево находится, у вас это `self.Frm1`, плюс при размещении через `grid` нужно указать, чтобы дерево "прилипало" ко всем четырем сторонам ячейки (`sticky='nsew'` или `sticky=tk.NSEW`).

Также я думаю что вы хотели разместить полосу прокрутки справа от дерева, для этого нужно ее родителем указать `self.Frm1`, а не `self`.

Почему полоса прокрутки оказывается ниже - потому что у нее родитель `Main`, а у фрейма с деревом родитель главное окно (т.к. родитель у `self.Frm1` явно не прописан), получается, что в окне `root` размещается фрейм `self.Frm1`, а ниже него фрейм `Main`. По логике стоило бы прописать для `Frm1` родителем текущий объект (`Main`): `self.Frm1 = tk.Frame(self)`.

Измененный фрагмент кода:

```
ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.Frm1, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)  # <-- self.Frm1 вместо self
self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set)

self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)  # <-- sticky=tk.NSEW
ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S)
self.Frm1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # <-- self.Frm1 вместо self
self.Frm1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # <-- self.Frm1 вместо self
```

Результат:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Благодарю за ответ)